# Webpack reduce bundle size by not bundling specific libraries

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a legacy react app that I'd like to optimize in terms of the bundle size. There are a few dependencies that I'm using that include a pdfjs-dist library.

I can decide not to use the functionality that requires me to include that library.
Is there a way I can ignore bundling of this dependency to slim down on the bundle size?

So far I've tried using externals, but this didn't work. I can still see the package in webpack-bundle-analyzer.

```
externals: {
        "pdfjs-dist": '',
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

> The bundler is supposed to bundle all the dependencies. You cannot simply ask it to ignore a certain dependency.

But in your case, if you are not going to execute the code that depends on the `pdfjs-dist` module, then you can use external to **fake** the dependency. You can simply say:

```
externals: { 'pdfjs-dist': 'X' }
```

Here, the Webpack will assume that there is a global variable named `X` accessible as `globalThis.X` or `window.X`, etc. Webpack will link all the invocation of `pdfjs-dist` to this global `X` variable. Point here is that your external configuration cannot have a blank string. So, as long as you not calling `X`, your code would safely work.

Further, to create a fake `X` so that when any property or method is called **accidentally**, instead of error, you can make it fail silently using ES Proxy interceptor. Add this somewhere in your initialization sequence as:

```
const handler = {
  get: function(obj, prop) {
    return 0;
  }
};

// Set as a global object using globalThis or window.
window.X = new Proxy({}, handler);
```